# What group level distribution to use in a multilevel model for a strictly positive parameter

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, regularization

I currently am investigating a model, in which one of the parameters ($\lambda$) is strictly positive. This model is fitted on multiple subjects, so I am using a hierarchical approach with a hyperprior on the group level. Because I only have vague knowledge about this parameter, I am trying to use vague priors to model this at the group level. Initially, I attempted to use a log-normal distribution for $\lambda$, where I restricted the parameters using vague priors:

Group level mean: $\mu_\lambda \sim \operatorname{Halfcauchy}(100)$

Spread: $\sigma_\lambda^2 \sim Exp(S)$

Individual parameters: 
$\lambda_i \sim \operatorname{Lognormal}(\ln \mu_\lambda - \sigma_\lambda^2/2, \sigma_\lambda^2)$

When I compared this to a model without a hierarchical prior (simply using $\lambda_i \sim \operatorname{Uniform}$), however, it looked as if the shrinkage was asymmetric (plotted on a logarithmic scale), with lower $\lambda_i$ receiving stronger shrinkage than higher parameters.

I eventually switched from the log-normal to a gamma distribution, because it seemed that this gave me more symmetric shrinkage.

Is my intuition correct here, that a log-normal leads to asymmetric shrinkage whereas a gamma distribution is more symmetric? Or is there a better way to handle shrinkage in this case? Is there some general method to determine if my model is shrunk correctly, or if my hierarchical priors create artifacts.